# Jquery Datatable serverside sorting and filtering performance

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

How to improve the sorting and filtering performance in data tables server-side processing,

I have 100K records and in my example below i show only 2 columns but i have 25 columns

here is my code

```
var allrecords = UserDataAccess.GetAllUsers(Uow).ToList(); // here i call ToList in order to use the count

    var totalRec = allrecords.Count;
    int filteredRecords;

    IList<User> filter;
    IEnumerable<User> sort;

    // filter
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Search.Value))
    {
        filter = UserSearch(param.Search.Value, allrecords).ToList();
        filteredRecords = filter.Count;

    }
    else
    {
        filter = allrecords;
        filteredRecords = totalRec;
    }

    // sort
    if (param.SortOrder != null && param.Order != null)
    {
        sort =
            Sort(filter, param.Order[0], param.SortOrder)
                .Skip(param.Start)
                .Take(param.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        sort = filter.Skip(param.Start)
                .Take(param.Length);
    }


internal static IEnumerable<User> Sort(IEnumerable<User> data, DTOrder order, string columnName)
 {
  var sortColumnIndex = order.Column;
   Func<User, string> orderingFunction = (
        c =>sortColumnIndex == 0 ? c.Name : sortColumnIndex == 1 ?
        c.IC :ortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.Age :"");
        var sortDirection = order.Dir.ToString().ToLower(); // asc or desc
        return sortDirection == "asc" ? data.OrderBy(orderingFunction) : data.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

  }

    internal static IEnumerable<User> UserSearch(string search, IEnumerable<User> records)
    {
        return records
            .Where(c => c.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                            ||
                            c.FuelAssembly.Lot != null && c.IC .ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
                            ); ;

    }
```

How can i improve this? i also the following code for sorting but my id gives an error

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, bool descending = false)
{
  if (descending) return source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
  else return source.OrderBy(keySelector);
}
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'

It takes ages for sorting and filtering

Comment: `UserDataAccess.GetAllUsers(Uow).ToList()` - You're fetching *the entire table* with every request.  If you're only showing a subset of records and columns, then don't fetch the entire table.  Perform your filtering and sorting in your LINQ queries so the database can filter and sort (very efficiently) before returning records to you.  This can include a `.Select()` clause which selects only a subset of columns into a custom view model as well, since you don't want all of the columns.

Comment: But i need to have the count of the total records which is required by jquery Datatables, or maybe there is a way to get the total count without fetching the entire table?

Comment: While I can make no guarantees to whatever `UserDataAccess.GetAllUsers(Uow)` does internally, LINQ to Entities supports the use of `.Count()` *much more efficiently* than materializing the entire table and counting the records in memory.  You can use `.Count()` on your expression tree and SQL will just perform a count operation instead of returning the entire table.